# How to tally entries by user, date

Tags: google-sheets

I am using a Google spreadsheet to track entries by several users. How do I measure their productivity per day? Or per hour? I have the timestamp field, a user field and other fields, but what I want to do is see how many entries per day each person makes and then chart them if possible.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsDPYrDDJkGldGJFeHNJWEhKMzlhOWp6c2JfRVFHMWc#gid=0

Comment: I have found some helpful formulas and am close but dont know if i need a pivot table or a formula for this

Comment: I would go for the pivot.

Answer (score 1):

> see how many entries per day each person makes

For this the time of day (part of the timestamp in ColumnA) is not required, so I have inserted a ColumnB, labelled `Day`, with formula in B2 of:

```
=ArrayFormula(int(A2:A))
```

Then pivoted ColumnsB:C with range reduced to relevant rows (ie `Sheet1!B1:C218)` ),  `Day` for **Rows**, `Name` for **Columns** and `Day` again for **Values** (Summarize by: COUNT), with Show totals unchecked for **Rows** and **Columns**.

Then selected the pivot table, Insert > Chart and chose Line chart. With other setting as defaults and a little formatting, the result (which I don't claim to be a meaningful measure of efficiency) was:

[image: WA42869 example]